# Change URL for already created project in Gitlab

Tags: url, gitlab

Unfortunatly, I created new project with `http://myip/myname/project`. But I want to change the URL to `http://myip/mygroup/project`. 
How to change to URL for the project without loss of project data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this is to transfer the project to the new namespace (`mygroup` in your case). To do this go to: http://myip/myuser/myproject/edit and there you open the `advanced` tag.

Under transfer you can select the new namespace (in your case `mygroup`) you want to transfer it to.
[image: transfer project]

Comment: We can also fork the project and can remove fork relationship. Is this forking method ok?

Comment: Before you answering, I did by forking project. I forgot about transfer option. Pity me :(